# Map format in 2d racing game

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, racing

I  have little experience in writing a simple games on XNA, but now i dont have knowns to solve my problem.

So, i want to write simple racing 2d-arcade, and i dont know how i can do maps for this game.

I decided do this so:

1. I draw a picture-map in mspaint. Black - its grass, white color -
   its road, red color - road markings, blue - water, green - forest,
   etc.;
2. After the image is loaded, I override textures in XNA - on white
       color i place texture of road, on black color i place texture of
       grass and etc.

So i have 2 questions.

1. I think in the right direction?
2. How i can to know color in desired pixel and how i can pour all white color, not each pixel separately? Second question not required, because i can just do second image with normal textures, and place this on second layer, right?

Sorry for really bad english. And thanks for answers advance.

[image: sample of map image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSDN forums, [man](https://profile.create.msdn.com/Profile.aspx?crn=Mad%20Martin) with the nickname Mad Martin [adviced do so](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/108381/639241.aspx#639241):

> Draw the final picture in paint with the mixture of textures like you
>   want it on the screen. Draw this texture directly. Now you'r game
>   logic needs to know where the road is in that texture. There are two
>   ways i can think of:
>
> - Make the road a spline and calculate the exact layout of the game. Probably a bit steep for beginners, but the most powerful.
> - Make a separate texture like yours with just two colors(black no road, white road). You can then check via the coordinates of the cars
>     whether you are on the road or not. You can do this either on the CPU,
>     by readign the texture into an array with Texture2D.GetData, or you
>     can do this on the GPU. Either way needs a little fiddling around, so
>     your cars dont hang on the edges of the road.

i think that it's quite useful answer, so i close question.