# How do I Implement the map in my race game?

Tags: c#, winforms, logic

Hello I want to create a simple 2D racing game via WinForms (school project I must use WinForms so please don't suggest XNA).

My current problem is that I need to Implement my map in the windows map for example:
[image: racing Map:]

I took it from: Saska
[Map format in 2d racing game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541214/map-format-in-2d-racing-game)

Anyway assuming its a fully functional map, How do I add it in to my project in what way?
if I put the whole map in the window it will probably be too small and hard to control the car, so I assume that I need to cut the map into pieces but I dont what is the logic behind it and how do I combine it with my project, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: What do you mean with `assuming its a fully functional map`? Is it code, that will update your car's position automatically? In that case, just look at that code and try to understand it first. If it's a school project, you'll have higher chances at getting your answer by asking your teacher or schoolmates.

Comment: what I mean by "assuming its a fully functional map" is that the map is complete and ready, not my code.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the code from somewhere, or did you download a .dll? If you copy-pasted it, you'll have to read the code and try to understand how it works and how to bind it to your game. If it's a .dll, there should be some kind of documentation available, that explains just that, and if there isn't, we can't help you either.

Comment: I dont have any code man I am trying to understand how to implement am big map into small screen, so when my car moves the map will adjust to car position.

Comment: If the map is an image, you can place it inside a PictureBox control at 100% zoom and adjust the location of the image to simulate movement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement the Form's Paint event (I assume you already know how to bind events on WinForms)

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("map.png"), new Point(0, 0))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("car.png"), car.Position)
}

public void Update()
{
    // Update the game here
    this.Invalidate(); // Invalidating the form will force it to redraw its graphics
}
```

More information: [Graphics class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)